# Get full directory path from ComboBox item?

Tags: c++, dialog

I am currently attempting to limit directory browsing of a "GetOpenFileName()" dialog, and am trying to figure out how to get the full path of a ComboBox item.  Specifically, how can I get the full path of an item?

For instance, if I have an "Images" folder, with the full path being "D:/MyFolder/MyStuff/Images", how can I get that entire path? As it stands, I am only able to get the name of the folder itself -- in this example, I can only extract "Images", with no information on the full path of the folder.

Thus far, I have sub-classed the dialog box and am able to intercept all Windows messages sent to it. I have been able to extract the text-name of each item in the ComboBox by finding the HWND of the item, then passing it to GetWindowText(). That only gives me the visible name, however, and not the full file path.

Is there any way to retrieve the full file path for a listed item?

```
//Callback function for OPENFILENAME struct    (the lpfnHook property points to this)
static UINT_PTR CALLBACK checkIfValidDirectory(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if( msg == WM_INITDIALOG)
    {
        SetWindowSubclass(GetParent(hDlg), MyCallback, wParam, lParam);
    }
}


LRESULT CALLBACK MyCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{

    switch (msg) 
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            char buf[128];
            DWORD controlCode =  HIWORD (wParam);
            int controlIdentifier = (int) LOWORD (wParam);
            HWND childHandle = (HWND) lParam;

            GetWindowText(childHandle , buf, 128);
            MessageBox(NULL, buf, "Alert", MB_YESNO);
            break;  
    }
}
```

The above code will alert the text-name of a given item in a comboBox, but how can I get the FULL-PATH of the item?

IMPORTANT EDIT: Ahh, I should mention that I mean get the full path whilst actually navigating INSIDE the dialog box! Not after a file is selected. I can get the full name of the file after I select it (aka, hitting "Open" in the dialog box"), but I cannot get the full path of the directory of which I am currently viewing in the dialog box.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Added! Let me know if you have any new ideas

Comment: I suppose you can get the full path without subclassing the dialog box. It looks like your problem is in incorrect use of `GetOpenFileName()`. Could you please show code where you call `GetOpenFileName()`?

Comment: Ahh, I should mention that I mean get the full path whilst actually navigating INSIDE the dialog box! Not after a file is selected. I can get the full name of the file after I select it (aka, hitting "Open" in the dialog box"), but I cannot get the full path of the directory of which I am currently viewing in the dialog box.